# Null check for every variable that invokes a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

I have a single javascript where I have declared all my variables in the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //variables
});
```

The values of these variables are initialized as well and mostly they are HTML elements. The elements are determined using the ids via `document.GetElementById()`. Some of these elements exists only in a different page which is not loaded in the browser yet. This results in null error when the variables holding the elements are used for a different purpose.

```
var container_element = document.getElementById('unique-id');
var count = container_element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
```

Since the element with "unique-id" is present in another page which is not loaded in the browser, the second line would return an error because `container_element` is null. To fix this, I changed the code to

```
var container_element = document.getElementById('unique-id');

if(container_element) {
    var count = container_element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
}
```

Is this is the only way to handle such a thing? Should I have to do a null check for every function that I invoke via a variable or is there any other solution or standard / best practice?

Comment: Yes, that is the general idea. If you don't know if you'll have an actual element or not, you check with a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a guard like that any time the element may or may not exist as of when you use `getElementById`. You can use the `if` you've shown, or

```
var container_element = document.getElementById('unique-id');
var count = !container_element ? 0 : container_element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
```

or similar.

Another option is to react to the exception:

```
var container_element = document.getElementById('unique-id');
var count;
try {
    count = container_element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
} catch (e) {
    count = 0;
}
```

---

I notice you're using jQuery but not using it in that code. Which is too bad, because if you were, jQuery's set-based nature would mean you **didn't** need the guard:

```
var container_element = $('#unique-id');
var count = container_element.find("div").length;
```

Even though `container_element` is an empty set, you can call methods on it. Most jQuery methods provide intelligent handling of empty sets. For instance, using `find` on an empty set returns a (new) empty set, as above.

You still have the option to know whether the element exists (more in [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) answers):

```
if (container_element[0])
// or
if (container_element.length)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I will incorporate this in my code.